# How to apply UIView shifts when scrolling between pages

Tags: ios, uiview

i'm trying to apply a shift effect to subviews of a UIView, but those shifts should'n have the same phase. A good example of that is the welcome screen in SoundClound.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, in the second image i'm scrolling to the second page, and the label slides more than the image (so it looks that the label moves faster than the image). So the subviews lose the alignment when scrolling, but recover it back if we stop the swipe.

Does anyone know how this effect is named? and where can i find some help to implement it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you are talking about is called the "Parallax effect" that Apple popularized in iOS 7. There should be tons of tutorials on Google on implementations

Comment: No, it's not the parallax effect. The parallax effect uses the sensors in the device. This effect is implemented in a lot of applications before iOS 7

Comment: You are confused, something in the foreground moving faster than something in the background to simulate depth is the parallax effect, it existed long before iOS7 indeed and has nothing to do with the sensors. Check out http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/08/parallax-in-ios-applications/?lang=en for "Parallax scrolling"

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. I though parallax effect was just using the accelerometer and other sensors. Could you put this comment with the link as an answer to mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Parallax scrolling" is what you want to search for.

Basically it is done by moving foreground objects faster background objects to simulate depth.

Check out http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/08/parallax-in-ios-applications/?lang=en for a starting point!